# How to best encapsulate features in code and enabling/disabling them at runtime?

Tags: python, clean-code, configuration, architectural-patterns

I would like to be able to abstract each feature developed by the team in a way that it can be enabled or disabled at runtime by using a distributed shared configuration system. Features are small and deployed daily.

What practices can I use to maintain the code clean and avoid series of if/else cluttering the code ? The codebase is mostly Python, has anybody ever tried using decorators for this purpose ?

Comment: I've done feature flags in c# but you always seem to end up with conditionals somewhere and it makes testing a nightmare

Comment: Really *each* ticket? So you mean also each bugfix, each UI change, each optimization? Do you have a good reason why you want to do this?

Comment: @DocBrown Ideally yes, everything. I won't go down this path, but I think being able to toggle immediately any change, at runtime, is a very powerful feature. I am just wondering if anybody had ever tried and has some experience to share.

Comment: At the very least you'd need a guarantee that every piece of code that can be toggled on or off is pure (no side effects). You're not going to get that from Python.

Comment: This is what source control is built to solve.  Modern source control systems will allow you to back out any individual bug fix or change (basically roll back all commits up to and including that one, and then apply every commit afterwards but skip that one commit).  However, for runtime switching, what you're describing is a [Feature Toggle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle).

Comment: Similarly, here's how [Flickr](http://code.flickr.net/2009/12/02/flipping-out/) does it.

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to be able to abstract each ticket developed by the team in a way that it can be enabled or disabled at runtime by using a distributed shared configuration system.
>
> Ideally yes, everything. I won't go down this path, but I think being able to toggle immediately any change, at runtime, is a very powerful feature. I am just wondering if anybody had ever tried and has some experience to share.

Don't do this! Really!

1) There is *no sense* in doing so

What is the reason behind *feature-toggling* a bugfix? Does anybody want the errorneous behaviour back? I do not think so.

2) You end up cluttering your code with many unnecessary feature toggles and unmaintainable configuration.

3) Your code becomes as a whole a moving target. The more feature toggles you have,the greater is the risk of side effects from a bad constellation of different features / bugfixes toggled on/off.

To get me right: *Feature toggles by itself are useful - no doubt.*

I am not advocating against the toggles, but against using it for literally *every* change.

Answer (score 3):

So you effectively need (or just want?) to have two source codes for the pre-ticket and post-ticket situation - e.g. ticket modified behavior of one method, so you ideally want to be able to switch from the former implementation (pre-ticket) of the method to the new (post-ticket) implementation.

This can be done using polymorphism - you have some e.g. service class with some method - ticket changes the method - you do this by creating subclass of this service, override the method and change the implementation. Depending on the switch, you use either former class or new subclass. This switching can be done using e.g. DI injection, where classes are instantiated depending on the configuration. Because you need to be able to do switches in the runtime, you probably need to use proxies instead of real implementations as the injected dependencies.

Of course, things are more difficult once the application has some state. If you modify the classes with state, you need to be able to convert all instances from the old class to the new class and vice versa in runtime - that means you need to have some converters (for both ways), some global registry of all objects, and conversion process should probably be atomic (e.g. you need to "stop the world" of the application until conversion is complete) to ensure that there won't be any problems in the transition period.

Then there's the problem that tickets are often not independent from each other - what if ticket 1 modified method helloWorld(), week after ticket 2 modified the same method. First question is - on what base class did it implement the functionality - probably on the subclass from the ticket 1. Then you can turn off ticket 1 and enable ticket 2 - you have dependency between these tickets which should be somehow resolved (otherwise you can have broken system).

In the real world - this is crazy and don't do this. Feature switching is normal practice, but on a very different scale and granularity - sometimes parts of the functionality (modules) are switched on or off based on licensing, sometimes parts of the system have multiple implementation strategies, but these cases are usually well defined and **justified** and even then they are far from free in the terms of increased complexity, testing etc.

Comment: yes it's crazy, it's goo granular as you say. Polymorphism would force OOP and leave out other paradigms so I'm not too fond of this approach.

Answer (score 2):

> What practices can I use to maintain the code clean and avoid series of if/else cluttering the code

Though your original plan sounds a little bit crazy, if you replace the requirement of "every ticket" by "a lot of different features", then the above questions makes IMHO a lot more sense. To my experience, the key to keep code maintainable when having a lot of different configuration options is

**breaking down different features into very small, mostly orthogonal subfeatures**.

"Orthogonal" here means that each subfeature is independent from each other. If you let the end user have direct acess to the switch of each subfeature, or if you group subfeatures and let the end user just choose between some complete "subfeature configuration bundles" is up to you, but orthogonality will ensure that the whole thing still keeps beeing testable. For example, if you have 3 customers and 10 different subfeatures, for customer A you enable them all, for customer B you disable them all and for customer C you enable every second feature - this makes 3 bundles, and you can provide a configuration set "config A", "B" or "C" as a group.

And even *if* there are some dependencies between subfeatures, as long as the dependencies are local and you can express them in terms like "this list of subfeatures is only available when subfeature X is active", such a configuration can still be handled.

This is not theory. I am currently working at a product where at least parts are highly configurable, with hundreds of different options, and it did **not** become a mess because we strictly focused on orthogonality whereever possible. Or look at the list of configuration options available in a software like the Firefox Internet Browser ("about:config"). Such a degree of configurability is IMHO only possible by paying attention to orthogonality.

However, this kind of design does not automatically emerge from your "tickets". For each ticket (or requirement, or "user story"), you have to think about if and how it makes sense to map it to some configurable feature(s) or subfeature(s). And you also have to make an individual decision how to implement that in code (maybe a conditional is the way to go, maybe by subclassing/polymorphism, maybe by utilizing a decision table) - there is no "one size fits all" solution. That's one of the important parts of software design - breaking down requirements to abstractions in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Facet](https://facet.run/documentation/) for enabling/disabling features.

> Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of the platform

You can think of facets as all the methods of your application. You can enable/disable methods during runtime. For frontend applications, you can also group DOM elements under a facet, and then enable/disable them as one.

To give you a perspective of how's that different from feature flags, you can think that facets are applied automatically to your application, rather than declared programmatically every time you develop features.

If you want to know more details, check out my [article here](https://medium.com/runfacet/announcing-facet-72c22748c16b).

Note: this is an experimental platform, with [Java](https://facet.run/documentation/java/) and [JavaScript](https://facet.run/documentation/javascript/) being the currently supported languages.